# RuntimeException not caught by customException

Tags: exception, runtimeexception

Why won't a RuntimeException be caught by my custom exception?

```
class MyException extends Exception { }

public class ExceptionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (MyException e) {
            System.out.println("I should be here....");
        }
    }
    static void doSomething() throws MyException {
        int[] ages = new int[1];
        ages[2] = 17;   // It throws a RuntimeException (ArrayIndexOufOfBoundsException)
    }
}
```

I would say, I should get the message: "I should be here...."
Because my exception "MyException" extends the Exception Class.
And a RuntimeException is a subclass of the Exception.

Why is a RuntimeException not caught by MyException?

Thank You in advance!

Comment: "extends" defines inheritance in Java, i.e. you don't modify or extend Exception class but create a new subclass. RuntimeException is not a MyException at all.

Comment: Hello Eugene, thank you for your answer.
In this case this means, that for example I can not create an own exception, which contains a group of exceptions based on java exception hierarchy? For example: "class MyException extends IndexOutOfBoundsException" -> I thought I can catch every "Sub"-Exceptions with my custom Exception too. For example here the subclasses of the IndexOutOfBoundsException: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and also StringIndexOutOfBoundsException. If it is not so, then what can i do with my custom exception? Is it only for cases where I throw it and I have to catch it?

Comment: Yes, your exception is mainly for your own use. If you create MyDataOOBException (which is a subclass of IndexOutOfBoundsException), any code (yours or thirdparty) which catches IndexOutOfBoundsException, will catch your exception as well, but only you know what so special is in your MyDataOOBException class.

Comment: What you can do is catch Exception, then inspect the actual exception's type and act accordingly (re-throw the exception if you don't handle it, or handle it internally).

Comment: Thank You Eugene very much!